# Изображения пропадают с Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Пользуюсь Paperclip. В девелопменте все ок, но на Хероку добавляю изображения к постам, сначала все нормально - все грузит и показывает, но через какое-то время все изображения пропадают - на их месте только названия файлов. В чем может быть проблема?

Heroku logs выдает что то про неполадки с путями:

```
2016-05-13T14:38:05.031223+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/system/posts/images/000/000/007/medium/app-server-arena2.png?1463131430" host=arcane-taiga-31170.herokuapp.com request_id=21181509-0382-494c-b4d8-fc0837464c99 fwd="92.100.233.26" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=1789
2016-05-13T14:38:05.029499+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/posts/images/000/000/007/medium/app-server-arena2.png"):
2016-05-13T14:38:05.027456+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/system/posts/images/000/000/007/medium/app-server-arena2.png?1463131430" for 92.100.233.26 at 2016-05-13 14:38:05 +0000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Да, Heroku так работает.

Локальный диск у него "эфемерный" и может быть пересоздан из образа в любой момент. А именно, когда приложение "засыпает", его диск уничтожается, а когда " будят", создаётся новый, отдельный на каждую машинку (dyno). Поэтому на диск ничего, что предназначено для длительного хранения, сохранять нельзя.

Нужно использовать внешнее хранилище. Можно сохранять прямо в БД (они не для этого предназначены, но в теории это реально), а можно подключить внешнюю службу хранения с доступом по HTTP вроде Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3), а можно придумать/найти что-то ещё.

Comment: Просмотрел варианты S3, Google и еще пару, но все требуют ввести данные кредитки. Очень бы хотелось этого избежать, т.к. есть опыт начисления скрытых платежей. Не знаете никаких сервисов с привязкой paperclip без ввода кредитки на первых порах?

Comment: @lif3ar прямо самого paperclip нет, но вам подойдёт что угодно, что предоставляет дисковое место и даёт доступ по протоколу, которому paperclip можно научить. Хоть FTP. Но вообще дисковое место по вполне понятным причинам денег стоит :) И на Западе к ним куда более серьёзное отношение.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, попробую на фтп залить. Согласен, это стоит денег, но Амазон пишет, что в одностороннем порядке начинает списывать деньги с карты при привышении квоты, а у меня не далее как в прошлом году на один из сайтов на протяжении нескольких месяцев ежедневно по 1,5-2000 запросов начало приходить через мусорные ресурсы.

Comment: @lif3ar расходы на такие аварии они [могут и возместить](http://www.behind-the-enemy-lines.com/2012/04/google-attack-how-i-self-attacked.html), но рассчитывать на это не стоит, да.